# How assert that "select" list has value or visible text using Page Object Model (Webdriver + Java + JUnit)?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests, assertion

```
public Select select;
public Select getSelect(WebElement element) {
    select = new Select(element);
    return select;
}
```

this is a function that I'll use in the test to assert that select has element visible by text, but I don't know how exactly assert that select has that element, I think there is a better way to do this

```
@FindBy(id = "...")
WebElement = mainSelect;

public void assertSelectHasElement(String string) {
    getSelect(mainSelect);
    select.selectByVisibleText(string);
    Assert...?
}
```

Comment: POM is a pattern for writing code e.g, warp each action(button/field and etc.) on the webpage in methods/function. Assertion is a different thing.
Java provide the assert Statement, just read the documentation. Also, if you use TestNg  read this :
http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/testng-reporters-asserts/

Comment: I know that POM is a pattern, also at this question I haven't got a problem with POM, I don't know how to write Assertion for element in select list correctly. I wrote about POM in question title to show why structure of the code is like I indicated

Comment: Ok, review the link of my previous post. It might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `List<WebElement> allOptions = select.getOptions();` to get all options of the `Select`, and then iterate through them until the option is found (or not), e.g.:

```
@FindBy(id = "...")
private WebElement mainSelect;

public void assertSelectedValue(String value)
    select = getSelect(mainSelect);
    List<WebElement> options = select.getOptions();
    boolean optionExists = false;
    for (WebElement e : options) {
        if (e.getText().equals(value)) {
           optionExists = true;
           break;
        }
    }
    assertTrue("Option x should exist", optionExists);
}
```

Comment: using this example where I should enter WebElement of my select named "mainSelect"? And at part `for (WebElement e : options)` "options" glows red

Comment: options is the result of the select.getOptions(). Edited to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one selected value in dropdown, below way helps.

```
//method to assert selected value in dropdown
public void assertSelectedValue(String expectedSelectedValue){

    WebElement option = getSelect(webelement).getFirstSelectedOption();
    String actualSelectedItem = option.getText();
    Assert.assertEquals(actualSelectedItem, expectedSelectedValue);
}

//method to select options by visible text in dropdown
public void selectDropdownOption(String optionToSelect){
    getSelect(webelement).selectByVisibleText(optionToSelect);
}
```

if there is multiple options selected in dropdown then use provided logic in another answer by katrihpl.

Comment: used testNG assertion.

Comment: yes, I've multiple options in select list so this example doesn't work for me, but thanks anyway, I think this option will also come in handy sometime